# sqlite net extensions InsertOrReplaceWithChildren not inserting children foreign key fields

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net

I have the following classes:

```
class A
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int A_ID { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations=CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<B> Children { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int B_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(C))]
    public int C_ID { get; set; }
}

class C
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int C_ID { get; set; }
}
```

When I have an instance of A, with child instances of B, doing a `db.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(aInstance, recursive: true);`
does indeed cause A and it's children B to be inserted into the database, however every foreign key value `B.C_ID` is always the default 0, despite them having a value.

example:

```
A aInstance = new A();
aInstance.A_ID = 1;

B bInstance = new B();
bInstance.B_ID = 1;

C cInstance = new C();
cInstance.C_ID = 1;

bInstance.C_ID = cInstance.C_ID; //assigning the many-to-one foreign key of B to C
aInstance.Children.Add(bInstance); //assigning the one-to-many child record of A to B

//do the insert
db.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(aInstance, recursive:true);
```

When I select the record B:

```
B bDatabaseRecord = db.Get<B>(bRecord => bRecord.B_ID == bInstance.B_ID).First();
//bDatabaseRecord.C_ID is 0      <-- the problem
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was solved by identifying an object of class C in class B ( as the foreign key object) and marking the relationship as ReadOnly=true .
so the code should be

```
class A
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int A_ID { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations=CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<B> Children { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int B_ID { get; set; }

    [OneToOne(ReadOnly=true)]
    public C C_Obj { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(C))]
    public int C_ID { get; set; }
}

class C
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int C_ID { get; set; }
}
```

I hope this solution works for you :)